# Specifying path to python executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Let's say you have a large, distributed project with hundreds of scripts and some of those depend on Python. They date back 10 or 15 years.  Those script start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Migrating to a world of Python3 (because everything really must switch to Python3) it seems there are two choices:

1. Install python-is-python3

```
apt-get install python-is-python3
```

Or,

2. Update the individual files over time.  Set them to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Both should work. The question is, which would be recommended?  If the long term plan is for Python2 to be completely obsolete, and Python3 will be required, then perhaps in a couple years `/usr/bin/python` will link to Python3 *by default*. Then it would be logical to continue using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0394/

Comment: Using virtual environments is not an option? There python and python3 are the same as pip and pip3.

Answer (score 0):

Because both Python 3 has been around for quite a while, its developers have already released support and different tools to help ease the transition when it happened. They did not simply do a complete deprecation and leave it to people that are not part of the official Python dev team to fix problems caused by the deprecation. Support for the transition ended in 2020.

But, if the team at Python does change the default path in the future (like in an update to something like Python 3.13 or farther into the future), they will likely release support for the transition.

Comment: Python *is already passed its offiial end of life*. There was over a decade of transition support, which finally ended in 2020.